# The query is too large. The maximum standard SQL query length is 1024.00K characters, including comments and white space characters

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am running this query in bigquery where I am selecting the data of `mobile_ids` which match in the array of strings. But when I increase the number of size of array of strings, it shows error:

```
Error: The query is too large. The maximum standard SQL query length is 1024.00K characters, including comments and white space characters.
```

My code is:

```
SELECT *,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE "Asia/Kolkata") FROM \`mytable\` WHERE (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE "Asia/Kolkata") <=6 OR EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE "Asia/Kolkata") >=22) AND mobile_id in UNNEST(${array_of_strings}) ;
```

Array of strings is["mobile_Id1","mobile_id_2"........]

Comment: What is `${array_of_strings}`?

Comment: You'd better create a table to store an array of strings and use it in your query instead of hard-coding all the  strings inside the query.

Comment: @Jaytiger.Will it be a good idea becuase i am sending different array of strings every time.